# Intent Flags between Activity

Tags: android-intent

I create my first android application.
I have an application with 2 activity A ans B. 
My activity A creates a HTTP connection and receives data. Then, this activity sends data to the activity B.
My activity B shows the results and if the user wants to do a modification, an intent is sent to activity A to modify the data on server. And when this modification is done I would like to return to activity B.

I would like to have a progress bar during the loading of data on activty A and after, see the activity B. When activity B send an intent in order to modify data, I would like that the user can see the interface of activity A.

For the moment, I use Intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT); 
So I see : Activity A, Activity B but after that I can't see again my activty A.

I think I don't understand every thing, if someone can help me ?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfect situation for using Fragments. It is very easy to choose which fragment is displayed by means of the FragmentManager.

Please read about it here,

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html